# Plotting 2 arrays against each other on mathematica

Tags: plotting

```
n = 1;
num = (1 - 0.01)/0.01
phi = 0;
For[i = 0, i < num, i++ ,  
    phi = phi + 0.01;
 a = NDSolve[{y''[x] - phi*y[x]^n == 0, y'[0] == 0, y[1] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 0, 1}];
   diff = Evaluate[y'[1] /. a];
 eta = Evaluate[(diff/phi^2)*((n + 1)/2)];
 etastore[i] = eta;

 phistore[i] = phi;
 ]
```

How do I plot `etastore` versus `phistore`?

Comment: First, you would have to actually define etastore and phistore. In your code, they are not assigned anything. For instance, you would need to use `etastore[[i]]` instead of `etastore[i]`.

Comment: @bills Though probably not good practice in this case, `etastore[i]` can be used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on coding based on the existing code:

```
Table[{phistore[i], etastore[i][[1]]}, {i, num}] // ListLinePlot
```

But why not:

```
Clear@phi
asol[phi_][x_] = 
 y[x] /. First@DSolve[{y''[x] - phi*y[x]^n == 0, y'[0] == 0, y[1] == 1}, y, x]

Plot[asol[phi]'[1]/phi^2 (n + 1)/2, {phi, 0, 1}]
```

If you need a numeric solution:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] - phi*y[x]^n == 0, y'[0] == 0, y[1] == 1}, 
  y, {x, 0, 1}, phi]

Plot[sol[phi]'[1]/phi^2 (n + 1)/2, {phi, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks... ur code was more concise! and better :) thanks!